# Django redirect not working in my view function

Tags: python, django

From my crop crop_prediction view I am trying to redirect it to 'http://localhost:8000/Efarma/crop_detail/' page but instead of this it render the current html page ,the home page which is also the starting page of this website.
Some error is showing in my console '[26/Apr/2022 22:31:29,457] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 62868)' but I have no idea what is it.
To go to crop_detail page i have to manually put it in search box.

urls.py:-

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('crop_prediction/', views.crop_prediction),
    path('crop_detail/', views.crop_info)
]
```

views.py:-

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Efarma/index.html')

def crop_prediction(request):
    global resultJson, firebase
    print(request.POST)
    print(request.GET)
    if request.method == "POST":
        N = float(request.POST.get("nitrogen"))
        P = float(request.POST.get("phosphorus"))
        K = float(request.POST.get("potassium"))
        ph = float(request.POST.get("ph"))
        rainfall = float(request.POST.get("rainfall"))
        city = request.POST.get("city")
        if weather_fetch(city) != None:
            temperature, humidity = weather_fetch(city)
            data = np.array([[N, P, K, temperature, humidity, ph, rainfall]])
            print(temperature, humidity, "--------kkk-------")
            my_prediction = pickle.load(
                open('CropRecommendation\model\model.pkl', 'rb'))
            final_prediction = my_prediction.predict(data)
            value = final_prediction[0]
            firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication(
                'https://e-farma-5dc42-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/')
            predicted_crop_info = firebase.get(value, None)
            predicted_crop_info["crop"] = value
            resultJson = dumps(predicted_crop_info)
            return redirect('http://localhost:8000/Efarma/crop_detail/')

    else:
        return redirect('http://localhost:8000/Efarma/crop_detail/')

def crop_info(request):
    print(resultJson)
    return render(request, "Efarma/crop_detail.html", {"result": resultJson})
```

error:-
[image]

Comment: There's a path in your view that returns `None`.

Comment: Can you please specify which one.

Comment: In case the condition of the inner `if` is not met.

Comment: The POST condition is met, and even if it is not met else also have redirect.

Comment: There is no `else` for the inner `if`.

Comment: The inner if is working I just check console it is printing print statements, and also entered an else for inner if. Still the same result

Comment: Right now you have `if weather_fetch(city) != None:`.  What do you want to have happen if `if weather_fetch(city)` **is** equal to None?

Comment: try redirect('views.crop_info') and investigate the 'localhost' part inside your url...note that the link in your redirect should only work if the browser you use is on the same computer running your website